# expose virtualbox vm to network

Tags: virtualbox

I have set up several ubuntu VMs using virtualbox. Right now I'm using network type as NAT and have access to it from the host machine, but what are the network changes  that are needed to access these VMs through putty from other machines that are connected to the same network(wifi) ?

Answer (score 3):

figured it out myself, first turn off the VM.
 - enable two network adapters 
 - 1) host only - to connect between host and guest machines
 - 2) Bridged network - to expose the vm to the network and assign ip address for each vm through dhcp

note: In my case I used vagrant tool to spin up my VMs, hence assigned fixed private ip to each vm,by enabling host only..I could do a headless start and then log in to VMs through putty(using fixed private ip) and get the dynamic bridge network ip.